# Vibration propagation

Tags: waves, vibrations

I have a problem in understanding the vibration propagation in an object. Supposing I have an object with an exciter positioned inside it. If I make the exciter runs producing vibrations at a certain frequency making the object vibrates, do the waves have the same frequency or during the propagation it can change?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the vibration frequency will remain the same.  In some circumstances, such as intermittent contact ("rattle") the frequency can change or higher harmonics can be added.  But, generally, the frequency stays the same as the wave propagates through the structure.